# Crear una variable según unas condiciones de otra variable contenida en un dataframe y posteriormente añadir la variable creada al dataframe en R

Tags: base-de-datos, r, variables, condiciones, dataframe

Estoy trabajando con la encuesta nacional de salud en España (ENSE). En ella se pregunta a los encuestados por su nacionalidad en forma de **4 preguntas de respuesta binaria (1 en caso afirmativo, 2 en caso negativo)**:

- ¿nacionalidad española?:      E2_1a
- ¿nacionalidad extranjera?:    E2_1b
- No sabe:                      E2_1c
- No contesta:                  E2_1d

Pues lo que necesito es **crear una sola variable a partir de estas 4**, asignando un valor a cada respuesta afirmativa de las dos primeras preguntas y otro para cuando se contestó que no sabe o no contesta, añadir un valor más para aquellos que tengan la doble nacionalidad( un 1 en las dos primeras preguntas).

Además, si en algún caso el encuestado puso respuesta afirmativa en alguna o ambas de las 2 primeras preguntas y también en las 2 últimas (Esto querría decir que el encuestado afirma tener una nacionalidad pero que a la vez no la sabe o na la confiesa, lo cual es ilógico) o si su respuesta fue negativa en todos los casos, eliminar estas observaciones.

```
E2_1a   E2_1b   E2_1c   E2_1d   E2
1       2       2       2       A
1       1       2       2       C
1       2       2       2       A
1       2       2       2       A
1       2       2       2       A
1       2       2       2       A
1       2       2       2       A
1       2       2       2       A
2       1       2       2       B
1       2       2       2       A
1       1       2       2       D
```

En la anterior tabla del dataframe, **la variable E2 es la que necesito** y las demás son las del dataframe (las que ya tengo). **Todos los valores son NO numéricos** y prefiero que la variable E2 también lo sea, por eso utilizo los siguientes valores:

- A: nac. española
- B: nac. extranjera
- C: doble nac.
- D: No sabe/no contesta

Por último, el código que he intentado hasta ahora en referencia a esta pregunta simplemente asigna un valor (de 1 a 4) a cada respuesta afirmativa de las variables del dataframe. Mi muestra es de 57068 observaciones, por eso primero creo la variable E2 y le pongo a todas ellas un valor cualquiera (5), el resto de variables se encuentra en el dataframe llamado DATA1.

```
E2<-rep(5,times=57068)

for(i in 1:nrow(DATA1)){ 

  if   (DATA1$E2_1a=="1"){E2[i,]=1}
  else (DATA1$E2_1b=="1"){E2[i,]=2}
  else (DATA1$E2_1c=="1"){E2[i,]=3}
  else (DATA1$E2_1d=="1"){E2[i,]=4}
}
```

Arreglar este fragmento de mi código me bastaría para poder seguir avanzando en la respuesta a la pregunta principal por mi propia cuenta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No necesitas iterar sobre los datos, en R base dispones de `ifelse()` una función vectorial que permite aplicar el condicional a todo un vector:

```
DATA1$E2 <- ifelse(DATA1$E2_1a == 1 & DATA1$E2_1b == 1, "C",
                   ifelse(DATA1$E2_1a == 1 & DATA1$E2_1b != 1, "A",
                          ifelse(DATA1$E2_1a != 1 & DATA1$E2_1b == 1, "B", "D")
                          )
                   )
```

Otra forma muy compacta, si ya usaras `dplyr` es el `case_when()`, en este caso combinado con el `with()` para evitar escribir siempre el nombre de `data.frame`:

```
library("dplyr")

with(DATA1,
  case_when(
    E2_1a == 1 & E2_1b == 1 ~ "C",  # Doble nacionalidad
    E2_1a == 1 & E2_1b != 1 ~ "A",  # Española
    E2_1a != 1 & E2_1b == 1 ~ "B",  # Extranjera
    TRUE ~ "D"                      # NS/NC
  )
) -> DATA1$E2
```

Por otro lado, te recomiendo no usar los valores `c(1,2)` para indicar un `Verdadero / Falso`, es preferible usar `c(1,0)` ya que estos de traducen naturalmente a `Verdadero / Falso`,

Comment: @juanluisAndiónTápiz, si no tienes control sobre el archivo, puedes obviar mi recomendación. Mi respuesta de todas formas considera solo condiciones Verdaderas, por lo que debería ser consistente con los datos que ya tienes.